# Is there a shortcut to comment multiple lines in python using VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Instead of indivually typing out a hash tag in front of each line, is there a way to select a block of code and comment/uncomment everything by only pressing a couple shortcut keys?

Comment: select, `cmd + /`

Comment: `ctrl + /` for windows

Comment: please what if i have in my mac '/' over the '7'? cmd+...?

Answer (score 2):

Select all of the lines and do one of the following:

- Windows: Ctrl + /
- Mac: Cmd + /

All shortcuts:

- Windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf
- Mac/Linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf

Comment: Cmd + / on Mac works for all the code editors... is there a way to change this shortcut? I would like to use Cmd + ' to avoid a conflict on one app. I checked System Preferences / Keyboard but could not find this global shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is select that code block with your mouse, then press the following key combination:

Ctrl + K then press Ctrl + C if you’re using Windows
Command + K then press Command + C if you’re on a Mac

You can also use:

Ctrl + / to comment and uncomment lines of Python code on Windows.
Command + / to comment and uncomment multiple lines of Python code on Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answers above all ignore a key piece of information the OP asked: **multiple lines** .

1. Use shortcuts **"Alt + left click"** (Select multiple lines, do not need the beginning or end of the line, any position in the line can be OK) to select all the lines you want to comment.
2. Use shortcuts **"Ctrl+/"** on windows or **"Command + /"** on MacOS

Answer (score -1):

add ' symbol three times at the begining and at the end of your code that you want to disable. And that is it. Please see the code below to understand better.

```
'''x=5
y=6'''
x=9
y=1
print(int(x)+int(y))
```

#above you can see the answer will be 10. But if you put ''' somewhere else your result will be different.

```
x=5
y=6
'''x=9
y=1'''
print(int(x)+int(y))
```

#above you can see the answer will be 11.

Comment: Hi, that's a doc string. I think what the author of the question was looking for is a short-cut to uncomment several linnes at once.